# C++ wclen in MSCV

Tags: c++, unicode

I using `wcslen` to determine the length of null-terminated wide string (`wchar_t*`), but I have some problems with this function in MSVC compiler

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>

int main()
{
    auto sc  = "The good and bad";
    auto wsc = L"Уставший лесник";

    auto ws = std::wstring(wsc);

    std::cout << "sc len:" << std::strlen(sc) << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "wsc len:" << std::wcslen(wsc) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "ws len:" << ws.length() << std::endl;

}
```

MSVC (amd64 16.8.2 x64) output:

```
sc len:16
wsc len:29
ws len:29
```

Clang (10.0.0 (GNU CLI) for MSVC 16.8.30717.126) output:

```
sc len:16
wsc len:15
ws len:15
```

Is it a problem of MSVC compiler, some undefined behaivor or nuances of MSVC implementation?

Comment: As UTF-16 is a variable length format (2 or 4 bytes), it's unclear to me from the MS documentation whether `std::wcslen` returns the number of Unicode characters or just the number of `wchar_t`s in the buffer.

Comment: @RichardCritten `std::wcslen` is a pretty dumb function.  It just counts `wchar_t`s .  If you're worried about surrogate pairs, you have to handle them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your file as either UTF-16 or UTF-8 with BOM.  MSVC doesn't seem to be able to handle a UTF-8 file without a BOM (which is understandable as the character encoding of such a file is a matter of interpretation).

Some editors (I am using Notepad2) call this 'UTF-8 with signature'.

Comment: There is also a `/utf-8` compiler switch to indicate the sources are UTF-8-encoded.  MSVC assumes the default Windows ANSI encoding without a BOM indicator.

Comment: @MarkTolonen So there is, I never noticed that.